# Sudo has lower privileges then normal user

Tags: 14.04, login, sudo, fstab, nfs

I have a strange problem. I am using `Ubuntu 14.04` and an NFS home folder, and currently if i try to log in i get thrown back to the loginscreen

I have a NAS, and the `home` directory is located there. I mount the NAS via NFS at my fstab like this:

```
157.181.240.65:/dlab    /dlab   nfs defaults    0   0
```

After that i modified my `/etc/passwd` file to point the `home` directory to a folder on my mounted NAS like this:

```
gerdos:x:1003:1020:Erdos Gabor,,,:/dlab/home/gerdos:/bin/bash
```

I created every file on the NAS with the same 1003 USERID and 1020 GRPID

Now after a recent update via `apt-get` i am unable to log into a graphical user interface (gnome flashback compiz).

I think some permissions are bad. I cant really use `sudo` on files in my home directory, even i clearly have a permission.

A strange one for example:

```
nano ~/asd # --> No problem, can nano it perfectly,
sudo nano ~/asd # --> Error reading /dlab/home/gerdos/.nano_history: Permission denied
```

Strange. Permissions on ~/.nano_history:

```
-rw-------  1 gerdos dlab       39 Feb 23 10:51 .nano_history
```

It is clear that i have read and write permissions, but `sudo` does not. I guess the problem might come from somewhere here, that i cant log in.

If i change the permission to 755 sudo still cant read it. On 777 it can. I would like to avoid putting all my files to 777.

How can i solve this problem? How can i "combine" the sudo on the NAS and on my CPU to work together? Is this causing the problem that i can login?

Comment: Your group do not have any rights or permissions, how come?
Can you log on like Guest?

Comment: How did you create the files on the server? What are the permissions of the containing directory (/dlab/home/gerdos)?

Comment: You do NOT place /home on a filesystem other than supported by Linux (ext4 would be the preffered one).

Answer (score 0):

That's a **feature** of `NFS`. Since `NFS` packets are not authenticated (they just say `UID=x,GID=y`, trust me), any NFS packets claiming to be from `root` (`UID=0, GID=0`) are remapped to `nobody`, a userid/groupid with NO privileges:

```
$ grep nobody /etc/passwd
nobody:x:65534:65534:nobody:/nonexistent:/usr/sbin/nologin
```

The other choice (A Very Bad Idea) is to believe the UID=0 in the NFS packet from Some Other System, and grant it `root` access to the NFS server/NAS. DO NOT DO THIS.